# Multiple source and header files accessing a common header file

Tags: c++, c++11

In my project I have multiple header and source files. Most of these files include a header file called `settings.h`
This file looks something like this

```
#ifndef EXTERNAL_H
#define EXTERNAL_H

#define processID 12
...
#endif // EXTERNAL_H
```

Now I noticed that if I change the processID from a define to a type such as this

```
int processID;
```

I start getting linker error. I wanted to know if there was a way for me to change the processID from a define to an int type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linker error is given by the fact that a symbol with the same name is generated in each source file that is including that header.

So solve that problem you have multiple choice but one in C++11 should be the way, which is the `constexpr` specifier:

```
constexpr int processID = 12;
```

Another solution would be to use `static` specifier but this will create a different variable with the same name in each source, only preventing clashes just because each symbol is hidden inside each source.

A third solution would be to use `const int` since a `const` value can't be modified then, regardless how many of them are generated in each source file, they would all resolve to the same value.

Comment: @Yakk: yes, it works but I consider it a hack since an `enum` is meant to represent a set of finite possible values, which is not the case in this situation. Indeed I don't even use `enum` anymore since C++11 but `enum class` which avoids the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted to know if there was a way for me to change the processID from a define to an int type.

The simplest way is to convert it to a `const` declaration:

```
const int processID = 12;
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use `extern int processID;` in the header, BUT you would then need to write `int processID = 12;` in *one* of the source files - this is because the `extern` keyword specifies that the actual object exists somewhere else, it doesn't define it. If you did not declare the int in a source file you would instead get a linker error saying the object isn't defined.

Alternatively, `const` or `constexpr` will reduce the object to a local scope.